# Python asynchronous requests (like grequests) with proxies?

Tags: python, asynchronous, proxy, web-crawler, python-requests

I'm writing crawler to monitor bunch of government sites and in seems they have some stupid restrictions on amount of page requests single ip address can do.

I heavily relied on requests earlier and later on grequests module for speed. But now it turns out grequest does not support proxies and I need high throughput downloading with proxy support. Should I just  use requests with gevent manually or there are better solution?

Comment: In what way does `grequests` not support proxies?

Comment: @MartijnPieters may be I am mistaken, but greping its source code for 'proxy' yielded nothing so I thought it does not support proxies.

Comment: It supports everything `requests` does; it just gives you a way to combine `requests` with the `gevent` module.

Comment: Why would `grequests` need to add specific support for proxies?